# How to configure maven in pom file

Tags: apache, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I have using intellij for creating a maven project.The intellij contains maven plug in apache-maven-3.3.9.When i deploy the project i got the following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project MyProject: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access scp://repo/maven2 with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access scp://repo/maven2 using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory: java.util.NoSuchElementException
[ERROR] role: org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon
[ERROR] roleHint: scp
```

Below is my pom file.

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>MyProject</groupId>
<artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        <id>corp1</id>
        <name>Corporate Repository</name>
        <url>scp://repo/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>

</distributionManagement>

<dependencies>
 ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
 </project>
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong here.Please help me.

Comment: you've copier the exemple in maven documentation [here](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) that's why ! you have to specify your own repository and yoyr own url to deploy

Comment: suppose i want to deploy it in appache webapp folder then what should be the configuration and url?

Comment: i deployed in tomcat long time ago , this is a tutorial that can may be  help (http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-deploy-a-maven-web-application-to-tomcat.html)

Comment: You need to set up your internal repo in `settings.xml`, and reference it via your pom

Answer (score 1):

The deployment in your example refers to deploying the project artefact (the war file) into a Maven repository somewhere in your organisation.

Deploying your application to an application container such as Tomcat is best done using a plugin such as tomcat-maven-plugin, see the tutorial that Hohenheim mentioned.